# Center a div inside an svg circle with Tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, svg, tailwind-css

I'm trying to center the `div` element with 29% value inside an svg circle. I've tried to center it using relative and absolute properties but it didn't seem to work

```html
<!-- Tailwind -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="relative bg-red-100">
  <svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
            <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="12" />
            <circle class="percent sixty" cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#f77a52" stroke-width="12" pathLength="100" />
        </svg>
  <div class="absolute inset-0 text-5xl font-semibold text-gray-900" style="font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;">29%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to limit the width of the container by adding the class `w-min`. Otherwise it will by default span the entire available width as the div is a block-level-element.
2. You need to add following classes to the absoltue positioned elements to center it: `top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2`
3. You can remove the `inset-0` class at it does nothing for you

```html
<!-- Tailwind -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="relative w-min bg-red-100">
  <svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
            <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="12" />
            <circle class="percent sixty" cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#f77a52" stroke-width="12" pathLength="100" />
        </svg>
  <div class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 text-5xl font-semibold text-gray-900" style="font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;">29%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You did not define the width/height of the parent container. A simpler approach could also be using flexbox instead of relative/absolute positioning. Especially when it comes to vertical alignment of text within a container.

```html
<!-- Tailwind -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="flex justify-center items-center bg-red-100 w-min">
  <svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
            <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="12" />
            <circle class="percent sixty" cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#f77a52" stroke-width="12" pathLength="100" />
        </svg>
  <div class="absolute w-min flex items-center justify-center text-5xl font-semibold text-gray-900" style="font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;">29%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add padding in the `div of 29%` .

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="relative bg-red-100 ">
  <svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="12" />
    <circle class="percent sixty" cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#f77a52" stroke-width="12" pathLength="100" />
  </svg>
  <div class="p-4 py-8 absolute inset-0 text-5xl font-semibold text-gray-900" style="font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;">29%</div>
</div>
```